# when i am using div command for footer, if i make one font size bigger,the other one automatically goes down,

Tags: html

When i change size of one text,the other one on the same row goes down.

```html
<div class="footer">
  <a style="color: white; margin-left: 10px;" href="" "Returns & Refunds">Returns & Refunds</a>

  <a style="color: white; margin-left:450px; text-decoration:none; font-size: 35px " href="" "WESHOP">WESHOP</a>

  <a style=" margin-left:350px; text-decoration:none ;background-color: white; font-size: 15px;" href="">Follow US</a>

  <br>

  <a style="color: white; margin-left: 10px;" href="" "Phone Number">Ph:03014667736</a>

  <a style="color: white; margin-left:488px; text-decoration:none;  " href="" "WESHOP">UNIVERSITY</a>


</div>

<img src="all.jpg" style="width: 70px;height: 50px; margin-left: 510px">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us also your header (see if it loads any external css) any external css, etc. We kinda miss some information to see the problem. This really doesn't show us where your problem is. Next to that, your html has ALOT of problems. in your href tags are descriptions that dont have a key within your tag. Inline css is not really the way to go btw. Add it to a CSS file.

Comment: your html is invalid - you have  things like "WESHOP" without any attribute - probably what is causing your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` to keep all links in one row with below code:

```
.footer{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```